# Encrypted Persistence Kali usb won’t save

Tags: kali-linux, encryption, persistence

I am trying to make a encrypted persistent Kali usb. I followed this tutorial.

https://devanswers.co/guide-kali-linux-2018-live-usb-encrypted-persistence-windows/

It took me a while to get it to boot and get mini partition wizard to make the second sda2 partition but it worked. I was able to get sda2 encrypted but it doesn’t save any files. If anybody can help please do I’ve really have been stuck with this.

#Update
I am trying to make my encrypted Kali usb persistent everything I have tried doesn’t save any data or changes. I recently just tried to create the partition on thru Kali terminal following this tutorial.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?ab_channel=ComputingHUB&v=uziV7Fv1lu4

The drive is encrypted and I have to enter the password I set in the terminal to unlock it but nothing is saved.

This is the results of fdisk -l
[image: results of fdisk -l]

Comment: what is your question? ... not everyone would ask the same question here

Comment: Welcome to the site. When asked for clarifications, please don't respond in comments, but edit your post to include the requested information. Reading through the comments is rather painful, and comments are subject to removal without notice by moderators.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have created my encrypted persistent Kali drive. The fix was forgetting about using the mini partition wizard tool and just creating the persistent partition using gparted cmd line on Kali Linux live. As detailed on the offensive security website. After creating the partition and encrypting it everything worked fine. One more thing I would suggest to anyone else who has this problem use power ISO if on Windows. I downloaded 4 different live USB creation software, and they all gave me some type of problem.